# как заблокировать второе поле до того как первое получит значение

Tags: javascript, календарь

Доброго времени суток всем! С помощью гугла и своих небольших знаний в jQuery, сделал 2 поля для выбора дат из календаря, с ограничением дат. Но никак не могу понять, как можно заблокировать второе поле пока в первом не выбрано значение?

```js
$(function(){
   $("#from").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: -1,// 1 день назад - минимальная дата
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
         var minDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", selectedDate);
         $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);// мин. для 2 поля
         var maxDate = new Date(minDate.getTime());// копируем дату
         maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()+7);// от выбранной +7 дней
         $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDate);// макс. для 2 поля
      }
   });
   $("#to").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1
   });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker {
    width: 216px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    font: 9pt Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.ui-datepicker a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-datepicker table {
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-datepicker-header {
    background: url('../img/dark_leather.png') repeat 0 0 #000;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 0px #000;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=1, offy=-1);
    line-height: 30px;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #111;
}
.ui-datepicker-title {
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('../img/arrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 600%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-datepicker-prev {
    float: left;
    background-position: center -30px;
}
.ui-datepicker-next {
    float: right;
    background-position: center 0px;
}
.ui-datepicker-prev {
    float: left;
    background-position: center -30px;
}
.ui-datepicker-next {
    float: right;
    background-position: center 0px;
}
.ui-datepicker thead {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%, #f1f1f1 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f7f7f7), color-stop(100%,#f1f1f1));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#f1f1f1 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#f1f1f1 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#f1f1f1 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top,  #f7f7f7 0%,#f1f1f1 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7f7f7', endColorstr='#f1f1f1',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.ui-datepicker th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 6pt;
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #666666;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #fff;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#fff, offx=1, offy=0);
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <span class="label">Дата1:</span><input type="text" name="fld17" id="from">
 <span class="label">Дата2:</span><input type="text" name="fld5" id="to">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дайте второму полю атрибут disabled:

```
<input type="text" name="fld5" id="to" disabled>
```

Добавьте в конец скриптов :

```
$("#from").on('change', function(){
    $("#to").prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
});
```

Чтобы работало не только при ручном изменении поля, но и при выборе даты из календарика, в начало колбэка onSelect для первого поля добавьте:

```
$(this).trigger('change');
```

Демо с поправленным JS-кодом тут: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvqZZ

Comment: Добавил еще в [демку](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvqZZ) очищение второго поля, если в первом удалили значение — может вам пригодиться.

Comment: Большое спасибо! А еще не подскажете почему в этой строке: minDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", selectedDate); при изменении формата даты(хочется поменять местами месяц и день и вместо черты, поставить точки) перестает автоматически закрываться календарь первый после выбора даты?

Comment: В этой строчке вы парсите уже имеющуюся дату (а не устанавливаете формат для календаря). Чтобы изменить формат в обоих календариках, необходимо передать свойство `dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'` при конфигурации `$.datapicker()` для `$('#form')` и `$('#to')`. 

Посмотрите [обновленное демо](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvqZZ), там то, что вам нужно.

P.S. если вам помог какой-то из ответов — пометьте его как "решение".

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте второму полю атрибут `disabled`, а при заполнении первого поля удаляйте этот атрибут.

```
$(function(){
       $("#from").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          minDate: -1,// 1 день назад - минимальная дата
          onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            //...
            $("#to").removeAttr('disabled'); // <----
```

HTML:

```
<span class="label">Дата2:</span><input type="text" name="fld5" id="to" disabled="disabled">
```